# Get textNames and colorNames From Local Nested Json File

Tags: html, node.js, angular, nested-loops

so i have these data.json where i want to fetch data to show in my html

here is my Component

```
tooltip: any;
tooltipColor: any;

ngOnInit() {
this.DataFactory.getLimitedData(this.widgetData).subscribe(data => {
        this.tooltip = data //this should hold the textNames from json file
        this.tooltipColor = data //this should hold the colorNames from json file
        console.log("this is tooltip --------", this.tooltip);
        console.log("this is tooltip color --------", this.tooltipColor);
    });
}
```

here is the HTML

```
<div class="tooltip">
    <span *ngIf="showHoverWidget" class="tooltiptext">
      <div class="textContainer">
        <span *ngFor="let colors of tooltipColor" class="textColor">
//this is where i want to display the colors from tooltip color in json file
          <p class="red">{{colors.color1}}</p>
          <p class="amber">{{colors.color2}}</p>
          <p class="green">{{colors.color3}}</p>
        </span>
        <span class="textParagraph">
//this is where i want to display the text from textNames color in json file
          <p *ngFor="let text of textNames">{{ text }}</p>
        </span>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
```

the JSON file data that i want to get

```
{
  "count": [
    {
      "clickable": [
        {
          "tooltip": {
            "type": "rag",
            "textNames": [
              "> or = to 1.5 million",
              "> or = to 1 million, < 1.5 million",
              "< 1 million"
            ],
            "colorNames": [
              {
                "color1": "RED",
                "color2": "AMBER",
                "color3": "GREEN"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

data-factory.service.ts

```
getLimitedData(widgetData) {
    return this.http.get(this.base_url + '/widgets_data/data.json'); //json
    return this.http.post(this.base_url_server + 'getWidgetData', widgetData, this.httpOptions);
  }
```

Really having a hard time figuring out, so here in the console log is the breakdown of what's inside the `console.log("this is tooltip --------", this.tooltip);` i called in my component. How can i get the data of my json file? Thanks in advance!

[console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSarP.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can consume `JSON` files by putting them inside the `assets` folder in your project, all files inside `assets` folder are served publicly once you serve your application.

Then in your service you may retrieve the information from `JSON` by using `HttpClient` just like this:

```js
getLimitedData(widgetData) {
  return this.http.get(this.base_url + '/assets/data.json');
}
```

> PS: You can't return two values of a function as you're doing in `data-factory.service.ts`, for that you may use a [rxjs operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators) like [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) to retrieve values from multiple Observables at once.